# VB windows form application text box where user writes a specific character and list of data appears

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

VB windows form application text box where user writes a specific character and (similar to search boxes for web applications) gets an dynamic list of data to choose from
I need to create a way for the user to write any specific sign or character and as soon as that character is spotted by my application to list all the possible values the user needs to choose.
Similar to what happens when you start writing something in the search textbox in web applications but this needs to happen in a vb form application.
I am fairly new with VB and I need to know if this is feasible.

Comment: Hi SteveNash2016.  Please consider reading [ask] to find more detail that would be beneficial to include in your request.  As it stands, this question is way too broad without some: code sample, specific problems, or at least a single explicit issue you've run into.

Comment: Also consider taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: will do sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to decide where the data (which will be used for autocomplete) comes from.

If you have a small dataset of words (which will be used for autocompletion) you can define a string array. This string array you can use for query after the textbox content is changed.

But, thats not pretty.

There you get much informations about autocompletion in .net :

http://net-informations.com/q/faq/autocomplete.html

Comment: Thank you very much I think this is exactly what I wanted. Can you please advise how to mark this as Answer?

Comment: I think you must hit the up-arrow-button on the left side :D